# Simple Continued fraction calculation

Tags: computer-science, irrational-numbers, pi, continued-fractions, python

When calculating the simple continued fraction expansion of certain numbers, how many digits of an irrational number $x$ (for example pi or gamma) do i need for a specific amount of continued fraction terms, say 1000? Is there a approximate formula which relates accurate simple continued fraction terms $a_n$ in terms of  used decimal digits $n$?

Comment: If your number is a "quadratic irrational" as in $\frac{A + \sqrt B}{C} $ for integers with $C \neq 0$ and $B > 0$ you don't need any, just one calculation of $\left\lfloor \sqrt B \right\rfloor$  Otherwise read Khinchin's little book, there are general upp and lower bounds on error. Note that I do not have any software that could calculate 1000 terms of the SCF of some number (irrational but  not "quadratic"), I don't believe you do either

Comment: There are lower bounds but no upper bounds. The reason is that the golden ratio has the slowest converging simple continued fraction expansion, but there is no limit how fast a simple continued fraction can converge because its terms $a_n$ can get arbitrarily large.

Comment: I think it is possible to do this with python. I already tested it for around 50 terms but don't know how many i can expect to be correct, hence the question. And arent the SCF terms for the golden ratio not all ones?